# Understanding what $H^{-1}$ means when $H$ is a subset and when $H$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory, notation

> A non-empty subset $H$ of a group $G$ will be a subgroup iff $HH^{-1}=H$

In this theorem, I don't understand what $H^{-1}$ means in both cases when $H$ is a subset and when $H$ is a group

1. Suppose $H$ is any subset. What does the notation $H^{-1}$ means?
   please explain with an example
2. Suppose $H$ is a group. What does the notation $H^{-1}$ means?
   please explain with an example

Comment: Fo a subset $H$, $H^{-1}$ means $\{ h^{-1} : h \in H \}$. It doesn't mean anything if $H$ is just a group.

Comment: does it mean anything if H is a subgroup and does $h^{-1} =1/h$

Comment: A subgroup is in particular a subset, but since subgroups are closed under inverses we just have $H^{-1} = H$. The point of the problem is that $HH^{-1} = H$ is a way to encode both the condition that $H$ is closed under inverses and the condition that $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Comment: @RaunitSingh: $\frac{1}{h}$ is not notation used in groups. $h^{-1}$ means the inverse of $h$ under the operation of the ambient group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $H^{-1}$ is the set of all inverses of elements in $H$ i.e. $H^{-1}=\{g^{-1}| g\in H\}$ of course, this notation only makes sense when $H\subset G$ for some group $G$. Say we take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\{1,2,3\}$ then $H^{-1}=\{-1,-2,-3\}$
2. When $H$ is a group $H^{-1}$ is again all of the inverses of elements in $H$. So if we again take $G=\mathbb{Z}$, the additive group over the integers. and $H=2\mathbb{Z}=\{2n| n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ then we have $H^{-1}=\{-2n| n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=H$